# Is it Possible to Parsing a complete CCDA xml file Using Go?

Tags: xml, go, c-cda

I would like to Parse an complete CCDA XML file by using any library available in Go. I tried to parse the CCDA XML file by using the https://godoc.org/github.com/clbanning/mxj library. In this one we need to go to specific path and parse the data but I want to parse the different scetions at a time by using the package or a library. I googled and ended up with no answers. It would be great if you guys help me.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to use a DOM library to parse the CCDA, and work on the resulting DOM model. There are several of them, one being https://github.com/lestrrat-go/libxml2, which uses the libxml2 library.

Comment: I would like to use a package to return all the different sections of CCDA XML document.

Answer (score 0):

[xmlquery](https://github.com/antchfx/xmlquery) to parse any XML document and extract any you want to data by XPath.

Comment: @zhenghun: I would like to use a package to return all the different sections of CCDA XML document.

Comment: If CCDA XML is a valid XML document, you can parse and extract some specified XML node from XML file using `xmlquery`.

Comment: Currenly I'm doing parsing using https://godoc.org/github.com/clbanning/mxj this package. By using this I can go to specific path and extract. If the path change in future it will not parse the elements right So I'm checking is there any specific package for CCDA files in golang.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Go, but CCDA is XML, so you can transform it using XSLT. I would assume Go has a way of allowing you to do that.

There are many CCDA xsl examples - it depends what you want the result to be.

eg https://github.com/hl7/cda-core-xsl